# Creating a sortable monthly "period" formula in libreoffice

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Every month I export data into a CSV format from a 3rd party site. The data is rows of daily data, the first column being a date field. Each month I have to manually add a new "Month Period" column to this data, and add this formula:

`=CONCAT(YEAR(A2), "-", MONTH(A2))`

I then drag this formula down for the entire dataset and then create a pivot table to give me the monthly sums for each of the columns.

But, now that we're into double figures in months, I notice the sort order for the pivot is wrong, where 2022-10 comes after 2022-1. One way to solve this would be to add a leading 0 before single-digit months, so 2022-1 becomes 2022-01, but I'm not sure I can do this with the MONTH() function. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

You are missing Grouping, you don't need an auxiliary column.

Create a PivotTable in the usual way, based on the original date column. In the PivotTable, select the cell with the date and [**press F12**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/guide/datapilot_grouping.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id4195684).

[image: Group By Month-Year In PivotTable]